# Can we conclude that two of the variables must be $0$?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> Assuming $$a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$ and $$a^3+b^3+c^3=1$$ for real numbers $a,b,c$, can we conclude that two of the numbers $a,b,c$ must be $0$ ?

I wonder whether mathworld's result that only the triples $(1,0,0)$ , $(0,1,0)$ , $(0,0,1)$ satisfy the given equation-system , is actually true.

Looking at $(a+b+c)^3$ and $(a+b+c)^2$ , using 
\begin{align}
&(a+b+c)^3= (a+b+c)^2(a+b+c)=\\  
&(1+2(ab+ac+bc))(a+b+c)= \\
&2(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)+a+b+c+2abc
\end{align}
and eliminating $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$, with $S:=a+b+c$ , I finally got  $$(S-1)^2(S+2)=6abc$$

I guess this is not enough to show the above result (if it is true at all).

This question is inspired by an exercise to determine the possible values of $a+b+c$ assuming the above equations, so this question could be a duplicate, but I am not sure whether it actually is.

Comment: You can try also like this: Write $$a =\cos \alpha \sin \beta$$
$$b=\cos \alpha \cos \beta$$
$$c =\sin \alpha \sin \beta$$
for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that $a\not=0$ and $b\not=0$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=1$. Then $|a|<1$, $|b|<1$ and $|c|<1$ (otherwise $a^2+b^2+c^2>1$). Therefore
$$1=|a^3+b^3+c^3|\leq |a|^3+|b|^3+|c|^3<|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2=1$$
Contradiction.

Comment: (+1) I will accept, if you show the "triangle-inequality-like" inequality

Comment: Which one? What do you mean?

Comment: $|a^3+b^3+c^3|\le |a|^3+|b|^3+|c|^3$ , which is "obvious", but a proof nevertheless would be nice.

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality twice: $|a^3+b^3+c^3|\le |a|^3+|b^3+c^3|\leq |a|^3+|b|^3+|c|^3$

Comment: Apparently, the exponent need not be "2" in the triangle-inequality. Can I prove $|a^3+b^3|\le|a|^3+|b|^3$ similar as the usual inequality $|a^2+b^2|\le|a|^2+|b|^2$

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality twice: $|A+B+C|\le |A|+|B+C|\leq |A|+|B|+|C|$. Then let $A=a^n$, $B=b^n$, $C=c^n$ for ANY exponent $n$.

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Since $|a|,|b|,|c|\in[0,1]$ (because $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$), we have
$$
a^2(1-a)+b^2(1-b)+c^2(1-c)=0
$$
The LHS is a sum of non-negative terms; to be zero, all the terms must be zero. This means that
$$
a^2(1-a)=b^2(1-b)=c^2(1-c)=0
$$ 
and therefore $|a|,|b|,|c|\in\{0,1\}$. Along with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, we get that exactly one of them is $1$, and two must be zero: this implies the result.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1)